# Is it correct to say " enough not to"?

Tags: grammar

Example :  You're mature enough not to listen to them.

Though it seems to ( implied command or advice ), it looks finer or better to say :

You're mature enough to listen to them. So why ( enough not to ) = Not firmly correct grammar.

Simply, if I tell someone ( You're mature enough to listen to them) = keep away from them at least at the present time. ( as long as you're still mature don't listen to them )
= correct grammar and understood. I don't agree with many people who are not native speakers using the language in a manner they want never thinking whether bad or good.

Do you agree with me ?   **I say ( enough not to )  is redundant.**

I can't consider how someone of you interpreted ( foolish or stupid ) !   By God does the following similar sentence include any hint to mean ( Foolish or stupid  ?   102 Issues in Grammatical Description — The readers may not be mature enough or linguistically advanced enough to comprehend it, even if there is space and knowledge.

Comment: Is it listen to them OR not listen to them??

Comment: You are mature enough **not to** need diapers; you are mature enough **to** see movies with nudity.

Comment: I copied as it is from one site like this one  (  WordReference ) You're mature enough not to listen to them.   I know many come online commenting or sharing thoughts and are never natives or hardly know the language.

Comment: Are you asking about (1) the grammaticality of the structure *[ adjective + "enough not to" + infinitive ]* in general, or (2) the grammaticality of your specific sentence, or (3) whether your sentence is *semantically* valid, or (4) whether it's natural and idiomatic English?

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken.

If we say a person is 'mature enough' **not to** do something, often immature, stupid or foolish, we mean that we expect them to use that maturity to resist any urge to do that thing. To act like a grown-up.

> Example : You're mature enough not to listen to them.

Here, the speaker is saying 'Someone as mature as you should find it easy to ignore (not pay attention to) what they are saying'.

The **not to** is essential. If you say 'You're mature enough **to** listen to them' you are saying something else. You could say 'You're mature enough **to** ignore them'.

Comment: Thank you  In our culture there is similar to the example I stated and explained  >> If we say to someone  ( You're still mature to do that or to go to a public evening party attend by old people = the same I explained ( we warn him not to go.   I think it is the same used in English  =  you are sufficiently mature not to listen to them.

Comment: You said ( stupid \ foolish ) I don't agree with you   Here I picked   If a pupil has the age, the maturity, the settled habits, the preparation, and the ambition to go to college—by all means send him, if you can possibly do it. if a pupil is not old enough, not mature enough to stand on his own feet, not settled enough to get down to work, not prepared to go, or has no ambition to go—by all means do not send him until conditions are more favorable.

Comment: And here is another example   By God does it imply any word = FOOLISH  ?    102 Issues in Grammatical Description — The readers may not be mature enough or linguistically advanced enough to comprehend it, even if there is space and knowledge.

Comment: Maybe stupid/foolish, not always. 'You're old/mature enough not to cry when a dog barks at you' or 'You're old/mature enough not to need your mother to accompany you when you go out'

Comment: Yes this one carries what you supposed  You're old/mature enough not to cry when a dog barks

Comment: @AhmadMohammad That is the situation of your question. Being mature enough not to 'listen to' (pay attention to, and worry about) what foolish or cruel people say.